# Can't get the value stored when updating attributes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, update-attributes

I am trying to do a marking system for moderators, in which they can select each item as "editor pick".

I've added a `:editor_pick` column to `photos` table(`boolean`)

and added a form in the partial for each item to have a checkbox in it:

```
<% if controller_name == "photos" %>
  <%= simple_form_for [@user, @photo] do |f| %>
    <%= f.input :editor_pick, label: "Portada" %>
    <%= f.submit "Pick" %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

after that, I required the new param in strong parameters in `photos controller`

It's redirecting me correctly after the update, **but it's not saving the new value**.
When I reload the page, the boolean is still `false`.

**My controller actions:**

```
def by_zone
  @photo = Photo.find_by(params[:id])
  @user = @photo.user
  render :index
end

def update
  @photo = Photo.friendly.find(params[:id])
  if @photo.update_attributes(photo_params)
    redirect_to [current_user, @photo], notice: 'El spot se ha actualizado.'
  else
    render 'edit'
  end
end
```

#### Edit

```
  def photo_params
    params.require(:photo).permit(:editor_pick,:url,:remote_photo_url,:thumbnail_cache ,:order,:string_tags,:tag_list, :sponsored, :photo, :terms, :title,:description,:category_id,:zone_id, :crop_x, :crop_y, :crop_w, :crop_h, sponsors_attributes: [:name, :description, :web, :facebook, :twitter, :sponsored_avatar])
  end
```

#### Params Edit

```
Started PATCH "/users/enrique-isasi-12/photos/rustic-plastic-table" for 127.0.0.1 at 2015-01-14 16:43:55 +0100
Processing by PhotosController#update as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"wB2SmOT0zR0dwIIguRhzFdctY51LX333CzGYelxS4Hs=", "photo"=>{"editor_pick"=>"1"}, "commit"=>"Pick", "user_id"=>"enrique-isasi-12", "id"=>"rustic-plastic-table"}
  User Load (0.5ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = 5 ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT 1
  Notification Load (0.3ms)  SELECT "notifications".* FROM "notifications" WHERE "notifications"."user_id" = $1 AND "notifications"."viewed_at" IS NULL ORDER BY "notifications"."created_at" DESC LIMIT 30  [["user_id", 5]]
  Notification Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "notifications".* FROM "notifications" WHERE "notifications"."user_id" = $1 AND (viewed_at IS NOT NULL) ORDER BY "notifications"."created_at" DESC LIMIT 30  [["user_id", 5]]
  Photo Load (0.4ms)  SELECT "photos".* FROM "photos" WHERE "photos"."slug" = 'rustic-plastic-table' ORDER BY "photos"."id" ASC LIMIT 1
   (0.4ms)  BEGIN
  Category Load (0.3ms)  SELECT "categories".* FROM "categories" WHERE "categories"."id" = $1 ORDER BY "categories"."id" ASC LIMIT 1  [["id", 2]]
  Zone Load (0.3ms)  SELECT "zones".* FROM "zones" WHERE "zones"."id" = $1 ORDER BY "zones"."id" ASC LIMIT 1  [["id", 6]]
  ActsAsTaggableOn::Tag Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "tags".* FROM "tags" INNER JOIN "taggings" ON "tags"."id" = "taggings"."tag_id" WHERE "taggings"."taggable_id" = $1 AND "taggings"."taggable_type" = $2 AND (taggings.context = 'tags' AND taggings.tagger_id IS NULL)  [["taggable_id", 26], ["taggable_type", "Photo"]]
  SQL (0.6ms)  UPDATE "photos" SET "editor_pick" = $1, "updated_at" = $2 WHERE "photos"."id" = 26  [["editor_pick", true], ["updated_at", Wed, 14 Jan 2015 15:43:55 UTC +00:00]]
false  ActsAsTaggableOn::Tag Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "tags".* FROM "tags" INNER JOIN "taggings" ON "tags"."id" = "taggings"."tag_id" WHERE "taggings"."taggable_id" = $1 AND "taggings"."taggable_type" = $2 AND (taggings.context = 'tags' AND taggings.tagger_id IS NULL)  [["taggable_id", 26], ["taggable_type", "Photo"]]
   (6.1ms)  COMMIT
Redirected to http://localhost:3000/users/enrique-isasi-4/photos/rustic-plastic-table
Completed 302 Found in 31ms (ActiveRecord: 9.7ms)
```

Comment: did you add `editor_pick` to your `photo_params` method?

Comment: you didn't show `photo_params` method

Comment: Could you post what your `params` contain? Specifically the value of `params[:photo][:editor_pick]`

Comment: and provide log of updating request

Comment: I removed "Pick" from the submit button and now works... BUT, it will update ALL of the photos and not the particular photo. Maybe some ID missing?